# How to get data from Laravel and Display in Angular?

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I have got a college project in which I will have to use Laravel as my backend and Angular as my frontend can you help me with how can I connect them using an api.

I tried searching a lot but could not get a stable solution.

Thanks in advance
Juned Adenwalla,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use API in laravel to connect with Angular and so I am a laravel developer, I suggest you to use laravel passport package to issue and authenticate token to validate request

Create api endpoints for login, register and other operations that you want to perform from angular app, all will be done through api in laravel

You will send request and get response from laravel then you have to decide what will you do in your angular app if request returns success or error then how you handle this in angular